# Why is the VLC library binding in Python not acurately measuring marked end times?

Tags: python-3.x, python-vlc

I am trying to write a tiny video editor in python. All works just fine, however, the function that establishes an end mark sometimes returns a time which is two or three tenths of a second earlier than the desired point. Note that earlier there. I would understand a delay due to human reaction time. It is a negative latency though. What makes it weirder is that the problem occurs only with the end marks and not with the start marks. Here is the code:

```
from moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip
import vlc
import wx
import sys

def ms_to_hms(ms):
    """Convert milliseconds to h:mm:ss.xxx"""
    seconds, ms = divmod(ms, 1000)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
    hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
    return f"{hours}:{minutes:02d}:{seconds:02d}.{ms:03d}"

class VideoFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title, video_path):
        super().__init__(parent, title=title, size=(800, 600))
        self.video_path = video_path
        self.init_ui()
        self.Show(True)

    def init_ui(self):
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.Instance = vlc.Instance()
        self.player = self.Instance.media_list_player_new()
        Media = self.Instance.media_new(self.video_path)
        media_list = self.Instance.media_list_new([Media])
        self.player.set_media_list(media_list)
        self.player.get_media_player().set_hwnd(self.panel.GetHandle())
        self.start_mark = None
        self.end_mark = None
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR_HOOK, self.on_key_press)

    def on_key_press(self, event):
        keycode = event.GetKeyCode()
        if keycode == wx.WXK_SPACE:
            self.toggle_play_pause()
        elif keycode == wx.WXK_RETURN:
            self.cut_clip()
        elif keycode == ord('S'):
            self.set_start_mark()
        elif keycode == ord('E'):
            self.set_end_mark()

    def toggle_play_pause(self):
        if self.player.is_playing():
            self.player.pause()
        else:
            self.player.play()

    def set_start_mark(self):
        self.start_mark = self.player.get_media_player().get_time()
        print(f"Start mark set at: {ms_to_hms(self.start_mark)}")

    def set_end_mark(self):
        self.end_mark = self.player.get_media_player().get_time()
        print(f"End mark set at: {ms_to_hms(self.end_mark)}")

    def cut_clip(self):
        if self.start_mark is not None and self.end_mark is not None:
            clip = VideoFileClip(self.video_path).subclip(self.start_mark/1000, self.end_mark/1000)
            output_path = "cut_clip.mp4"
            clip.write_videofile(output_path)
            print(f"Clip cut: Start - {ms_to_hms(self.start_mark)}, End - {ms_to_hms(self.end_mark)}")

def main(video_path):
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = VideoFrame(None, "Video Player", video_path)
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    video_path = sys.argv[1]
    main(video_path)
```

Comment: Sorry, but your code example is too large. Please remove everything not needed to see the effect, aka a [example]. On the other hand your observed effect may be quite independent of the code. Have you tried file that observation against the people of libvlc? For example open an issue at https://github.com/oaubert/python-vlc?

Comment: I surely will. Nonetheless, do you have any ideas on how to address the problem if VLC is failing for some reason? Would it make sense to pause the video, wait for two tenths of a second, and then register the ending time? What startles me is the fact that it works fine with the starting marks.